# Pandas get_group returns key error, even though key is in group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of football league stats stored in dataframe matches:

```
matches.iloc[: , 20:30]

sot dist    fk  pk  pkatt   season  team    venue_code  opp_code    hour
1   4.0 16.9    1.0 0.0 0.0 2022    Manchester City 0   16  16
2   4.0 17.3    1.0 0.0 0.0 2022    Manchester City 1   14  15
3   10.0    14.3    0.0 0.0 0.0 2022    Manchester City 1   0   12
4   8.0 14.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 2022    Manchester City 0   9   15
6   1.0 15.7    1.0 0.0 0.0 2022    Manchester City 1   15  15
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
38  3.0 20.7    0.0 0.0 0.0 2021    Norwich City    0   1   15
39  2.0 21.5    1.0 0.0 0.0 2021    Norwich City    1   18  14
40  5.0 16.2    0.0 0.0 0.0 2021    Norwich City    0   9   19
41  2.0 13.4    0.0 0.0 0.0 2021    Norwich City    0   19  14
42  0.0 17.1    0.0 0.0 0.0 2021    Norwich City    1   16  16
```

I'm trying to group by the team column using the below code:

```
grouped_matches = matches.groupby(by=["team"], dropna=False)
grouped_matches

Out: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7ff400036c70>
```

Is that what I should expect the output of the group_by function to be? Looking at the documentation, I was expecting another dataframe. Am I using this incorrectly?

This leads to my next line of code which returns the error:

```
group = grouped_matches.get_group("Manchester City")
KeyError: 'Manchester City'
```

Manchester City is in the original dataframe. I also tried other teams but get the same error. So why would this return a KeyError?

Comment: That is weird. Could you check the values in the team column to make sure there are no weird extra spacing or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't want to groupby, but simply filter your dataframe.

```
>>> df[df['team'] == 'Manchester City']
```

Use `groupby` when you want to apply some logic to each group (i.e. aggregate them, filter them, modify/transform in some way etc). If you just want to list the groups, then all you need is slicing and `.loc`.

You may also sort your dataframe by team to see it in a "grouped" fashion.

```
>>> df.sort_values(by='team')
```

Now, as to why you get a `KeyError`: your data is likely not clean. The group name must match excatly the values in your DataFrame. For example, if you have in your `df` the value `" Manchester City"`, with an extra whitespace in the beginning, calling `get_group('Manchester City')` will yield an error. The same is true for `\n`, `\t` and other invisible characters.

Make sure you have clean team names first. Usually, doing

```
>>> df['team'] = df['team'].str.strip()
```

is a good start.